# Just for reference: open-ended but answerable question?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Just wondering since while we already have this information it's somewhat scattered among near-duplicates: If someone asked "What are good ways to recognize that someone is trying to scam me", would that inherently be a bad question because it doesn't have a relatively small set of correct solutions (and might draw more opinion than useful response), or within our scope?

Comment: Related: [Why is the question about 'Value of time' not closed?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2767/10997)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a great idea. It is occasionally suggested that we turn one of the “Is this a scam?” question into a one-size-fits-all canonical question, but that doesn’t really work because the details of every scam are a little different. This suggested question, however, would hopefully generate a good answer that would list the different signs that we see that identify clear scams. I think it could work well.